# Jena: How to add properties with numeric values?

Tags: java, rdf, jena, ontology

How can I add numeric values like `float`, `int` or  `date` to a `Resource` using Jena?

I assume I'd have to use `resource.addProperty(Property, String, RDFDataType)`, but how do I instantiate the correct RDFDataType for the above mentioned data types?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The 'official' documentation on typed literals is here:
http://incubator.apache.org/jena/documentation/notes/typed-literals.html

You can use the **addLiteral** and **add** methods of a Jena **Model**, for example:

```
    Model model = ...

    model.addLiteral (subject, predicate, 10);
    model.addLiteral (subject, predicate, 0.5);
    model.addLiteral (subject, predicate, (float)0.5);
    model.addLiteral (subject, predicate, ResourceFactory.createTypedLiteral(20));
    model.addLiteral (subject, predicate, ResourceFactory.createTypedLiteral(0.99));
    model.addLiteral (subject, predicate, true);
    model.add (subject, predicate, ResourceFactory.createTypedLiteral("2012-03-11", XSDDatatype.XSDdate));
    model.add (subject, predicate, ResourceFactory.createTypedLiteral("P2Y", XSDDatatype.XSDduration));
```

**RDFDatatype** is an interface so you cannot instantiate it directly. However, look at classes implementing that interface. You'll find XSDDatatype is one of those classes. There are others.

If you want to see a **complete example**, have a look here:
https://github.com/castagna/jena-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/jena/examples/ExampleDataTypes_01.java. The output of ExampleDataTypes_01.java is the following RDF (serialized using Turtle format):

```
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix example:  <http://example.org/> .

example:s
      example:p1 "10"^^xsd:int ;
      example:p2 "0.5"^^xsd:double ;
      example:p3 "0.5"^^xsd:float ;
      example:p4 "20"^^xsd:int ;
      example:p5 "0.99"^^xsd:double ;
      example:p6 "true"^^xsd:boolean ;
      example:p7 "2012-03-11"^^xsd:date ;
      example:p8 "P2Y"^^xsd:duration .
```

Answer (score 1):

These are [literals](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-concepts/#section-Literals) in RDF. You can utilise, e.g., the [rdf:value](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_value) property to add numeric values as literals to your resource. You can specify [datatypes](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_datatype) on these literals, e.g., [xsd:int](http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77175.html).

Comment: how can we print datatype for string value?
e.g. model.addLiteral (subject, predicate, "test str");
it should print like this but not printing: example:p11 "test str"^^xsd:string ;